# Build failed with 4 errors for datastore

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, android-jetpack-compose

My Android Studio project couldn't build because of mistakes I can't understand. It says that it can't find the datastore dependencies even though they are there. If someone knows what is wrong, I would be glad to know. Thanks in advance!

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:compileDebugSources] in project C

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileLintChecks UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/datastore/datastore-preferences-android/1.1.0/datastore-preferences-android-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 910ms
11 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 7 up-to-date
```

Here is my gradle file. I putted the dependencies needed for datastore to work, but unsuccessfully.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.littlelemon'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.littlelemon"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-core-android:1.1.0-alpha04'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02"
}
```

Comment: What is in your repositories {}

Comment: I don't have any

Answer (score 2):

That's because the stable version **1.1** of `androidx.datastore:datastore-*` does not exist yet -- only the [alpha versions are available](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore#version_11_2).

Since you are interested in the alpha version, you need to remove the incorrect dependency in your **app** `build.gradle` file:

```
// use this
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.1.0-alpha04"

// remove below dependencies
implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android:1.1.0"
```